# How to remove handlers from presenter in MVP pattern

Tags: gwt, mvp

I am implementing MVP pattern in my GWT application. On each history token change, I am initialising presenter to get respective view. If user navigate to a single view GridView (say) 2 times then respective presenter GridViewPresenter (say) is initialized 2 times (according to MVP pattern. If we will not make presenter as singelton). 
like

```
 Presenter presenter = new GridViewPresenter();
```

In this case all events in this presenter will registerd and listen 2 times. How can we avoid this scenario without making our presenter singelton.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to track your presenters lifecycle (before switching to a new one, dispose the current one so it unregisters its handlers).

Alternatively, you could use the Places & Activities *micro framework* from GWT, that does just that: you activity has explicit `start` and `onStop` and `onCancel` (when started asynchronously).
GWT-Platform (an *MVP framework* for GWT) also has similar lifecycle.

Another alternative is to **not** have your presenter add handlers on its view: the view manages its event handlers, and notifies the presenter through a contract expressed as an interface (the presenter implementing that interface); and there can have only one presenter at a time for a given view (that way, the new presenter *overwrites* the previous one).
Managing your presenters lifecycle has the advantage that the presenters can be garbage collected as soon as they're no longer used, rather than waiting for a new presenter to take their place in the singleton/long-lived view.